# Grpc-message: Policy checks are unavailable

Tags: grpc, firebase-admin, http2

my firebase-admin client gets this message in HTTP2 header: "grpc-message" = "Policy checks are unavailable." and "grpc-status" = "14". client doesn't get any DATA payload in response. Does anybody have any idea about in what situation grpc will return this error message?

Specifically, I'm coding golang app on go/http2 to send a firebase-admin request to query my data on firebase. Here is the data flow of HTTP2. I expect to get `DATA` frame between the last two `HEADERS` frames as response but I didn't get it.

Also I checked this link grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html and didn't find the `grpc-message` I got.
I used firebase-admin js client to query my data and it's working fine. So I don't think this is service api issue.

```
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: wrote SETTINGS len=12, settings: ENABLE_PUSH=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=4194304
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: wrote WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=1073741824
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: read SETTINGS len=18, settings: MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=100, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=65536
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: wrote SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: read WINDOW_UPDATE len=4 (conn) incr=983041
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: read SETTINGS flags=ACK len=0
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header ":authority" = "firestore.googleapis.com:443"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header ":method" = "POST"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header ":path" = "/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/RunQuery"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header ":scheme" = "https"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "x-goog-request-params" = "parent=projects%2Flijie-dependencies-test%2Fdatabases%2F(default)%2Fdocuments"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "accept-encoding" = "identity"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "user-agent" = "grpc-node-js/1.4.4"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "te" = "trailers"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "grpc-accept-encoding" = "identity,deflate,gzip"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "content-type" = "application/grpc"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "x-goog-api-client" = "gax/2.28.1 gapic/4.15.1 gl-node/10.18.1 grpc/1.4.4 gccl/4.15.1 fire/10.0.0"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "google-cloud-resource-prefix" = "projects/lijie-dependencies-test/databases/(default)"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "authorization" = "Bearer [[REDACTED]]"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "grpc-timeout" = "299901m"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Transport encoding header "accept-encoding" = "gzip"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: wrote HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=3 len=925
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: wrote DATA stream=3 len=80 data="\x00\x00\x00\x00K\n>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\t\x12\a\x12\x05users"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: wrote DATA flags=END_STREAM stream=3 len=0 data=""
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: read HEADERS flags=END_HEADERS stream=3 len=176
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: decoded hpack field header field ":status" = "200"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: decoded hpack field header field "content-type" = "application/grpc"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: decoded hpack field header field "date" = "Tue, 25 Jan 2022 20:42:22 GMT"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: decoded hpack field header field "alt-svc" = "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\""
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: Framer 0xc00e8629a0: read HEADERS flags=END_STREAM|END_HEADERS stream=3 len=47
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: decoded hpack field header field "grpc-status" = "14"
2022/01/25 14:42:22 http2: decoded hpack field header field "grpc-message" = "Policy checks are unavailable."
```

Comment: Your question lacks necessary detail that would help us help you. What were you trying to do exactly? What commands did you submit? Was this the only error? I think the error is a GCP platform error and possibly intermittent. Has it recurred? Google uses the following gRPC status codes: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html

Comment: Google Status Dashboard (https://status.cloud.google.com/) is reporting issues with Service Usage API today and this *may* be the cause.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it's more clear. @DazWilkin

Comment: The "Policy checks are unavailable" message is (I think) coming from GCP to accompany the 14. I don't know what it means but there was another occurrence of it on the web and it meant that an incorrect endpoint was being used.

Comment: Are you attempting to interact with the service by writing your own client? You say "I'm coding golang app on go/http2 to send a firebase-admin request to query my data". Are you unwilling to use Google's [Golang SDK for Firestore (sic.)](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore)

Comment: I redacted a bearer token that you inadvertently included in your question. I recommend you take action to protect yourself from it having been published here. If you are using a Service Account, I recommend you delete the Service Account and create another.

Comment: Thank you. will do it. yes, i'm writing my own client for some specific reason. But I'll try the golang sdk to validate http2 flow.

Comment: I think you'll cause yourself a lot of stress trying to "roll your own". However, what you can do is run a parallel client using Google's SDK and look for diffs. Good luck!